# Unable to see the text returned from home and tutorials page in react-hooks site

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Unable to see the `header text` returned in my Home and Tutorials page in my react hooks site. Below is my App.js, Navigation.js and Home.js. Could someone please advise about the problem here.

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Tutorials from "./components/Tutorials";
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation>
          <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/tutorials" component={Tutorials} />
          </Switch>
        </Navigation>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`Navigation.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const Navigation = () => {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div id="wrap">
                    <nav className="siteNavigation_nav_links">
                        <div className="row" ></div>
                        <div className="main_links_nav">
                            <NavLink className="mob_link" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                            <NavLink className="mob_link" to="/tutorials">Tutorials</NavLink>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )

}

export default Navigation;
```

`Home.js`

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = () =>{

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>This is Home Page !</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Home;
```

`Tutorials.js`

```
import React from 'react';

const Tutorials = () =>{

    return (
        <div><h1>This is Tutorials Page !</h1></div>
    )
};
export default Tutorials;
```

Comment: The way you are using the Navigation is wrong.

Comment: the navigation component is not needed

Comment: If we add Navigation component separately won''t that be easy when have more links/ nested links ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation is a Navbar component. And you want it everywhere on the site.

So, you can easily do it by using it outside the scope of the `Switch` component.
In doing so, it will render all over your screens.

```
  <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation />
          <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/tutorials" component={Tutorials} />
          </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: So if we add the `<Switch>` inside the navigation tags it wont that way ?

Comment: Why should you add Switch inside the navigation tags?

Comment: Later I am planning to implement protected route and nested routes so think switch might be helpful

Comment: I don't think you need to use Switch inside your navigations tags.

Comment: Much appreciate your help, I will further investigate on that. Upvoted and accepted your ans already !

Comment: Could you please help me with this problem here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63985577/on-click-on-link-should-create-open-an-html-page-in-react-hooks-site-with-conten