# On click on link should create/open an html page in react-hooks site with contents displaying

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, contentful

I have integrated my `React-hooks` website with `contentful`. Now I am able to see contents from contentful website in my react site. On click on `...more >>` link under each tile I would like to display the contents received to open in a `separate` html page, so that I can view full content of the post. Can someone please advise me on how can I achieve that ? ( Home tab > screenshot of tiles )

[image]

`Demo`

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-lamarr-fo917

`Home.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const items = [
  {
    sys: {
      space: {
        sys: {
          type: "Link",
          linkType: "Space",
          id: "pih85ghtkifg"
        }
      },
      id: "2L5jhZhtvUwuWe20kYM2vh",
      type: "Entry",
      createdAt: "2020-09-20T11:50:53.764Z",
      updatedAt: "2020-09-20T11:50:53.764Z",
      environment: {
        sys: {
          id: "master",
          type: "Link",
          linkType: "Environment"
        }
      },
      revision: 1,
      contentType: {
        sys: {
          type: "Link",
          linkType: "ContentType",
          id: "course"
        }
      },
      locale: "en-US"
    },
    fields: {
      title: "API testing using Postman",
      slug: "api-testing-using-postman",
      image: {
        sys: {
          type: "Link",
          linkType: "Asset",
          id: "6n41KgxfwWmmeCiSemIsK2"
        }
      },
      shortDescription: "Cypress test to read a JSON file from Fixture folder.",
      description:
        "Api testing using postman. This is useful for testers.\n\npm.test()\n\nApi testing using postman. This is useful for testers. \n",
      duration: 3,
      skillLevel: "beginner",
      lessons: [
        {
          sys: {
            type: "Link",
            linkType: "Entry",
            id: "3op5VIqGZiwoe06c8IQIMO"
          }
        }
      ],
      categories: [
        {
          sys: {
            type: "Link",
            linkType: "Entry",
            id: "7JhDodrNmwmwGmQqiACW4"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    sys: {
      space: {
        sys: {
          type: "Link",
          linkType: "Space",
          id: "pih85ghtkifg"
        }
      },
      id: "1ePcCVp2VzehrXpcSaq6aM",
      type: "Entry",
      createdAt: "2020-09-20T08:43:44.388Z",
      updatedAt: "2020-09-20T08:43:44.388Z",
      environment: {
        sys: {
          id: "master",
          type: "Link",
          linkType: "Environment"
        }
      },
      revision: 1,
      contentType: {
        sys: {
          type: "Link",
          linkType: "ContentType",
          id: "course"
        }
      },
      locale: "en-US"
    },
    fields: {
      title: "Cypress test to read a JSON file",
      slug: "cypress-test-to-read-a-json-file",
      image: {
        sys: {
          type: "Link",
          linkType: "Asset",
          id: "6n41KgxfwWmmeCiSemIsK2"
        }
      },
      shortDescription: "Cypress test to read a JSON file from Fixture folder.",
      description:
        "\nThis cy test is to read a JSON file from fixture folder. This cy test is to read a JSON file from fixture folder. This cy test is to read a JSON file from fixture folder. This cy test is to read a JSON file from fixture folder. This cy test is to read a JSON file from fixture folder. This cy test is to read a JSON file from fixture folder. \n\n> cy.get()\n\nThis cy test is to read a JSON file from fixture folder. This cy test is to read a JSON file from fixture folder. This cy test is to read a JSON file from fixture folder. \n",
      duration: 3,
      skillLevel: "beginner",
      lessons: [
        {
          sys: {
            type: "Link",
            linkType: "Entry",
            id: "3op5VIqGZiwoe06c8IQIMO"
          }
        }
      ],
      categories: [
        {
          sys: {
            type: "Link",
            linkType: "Entry",
            id: "7JhDodrNmwmwGmQqiACW4"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

const Home = () => {
  const [blogArticles, setBlogArticles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setBlogArticles(items);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        {blogArticles.map(
          ({
            sys: { id },
            fields: {
              title,
              image,
              shortDescription,
              description,
              skillLevel,
              duration
            }
          }) => (
            <div key={id} className="column-center">
              <article key={id} className="blogmaintile">
                <img
                  className="blogImage"
                  key={image}
                  src={image}
                  alt="myimg"
                ></img>
                <div className="blogtitle">
                  <span key={title}>{title}</span>
                </div>
                <section>
                  <p className="blogdescription" key={shortDescription}>
                    {shortDescription}
                  </p>
                </section>
                <section>
                  <p className="blogdescription" key={description}>
                    {description}
                  </p>
                </section>

                <section className="col2">
                  <a href="">
                    Read more {">"}
                    {">"}
                  </a>
                </section>
              </article>
            </div>
          )
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of react/javascript. Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24534492/1642627).

You can easily achieve this with the help of bootstrap. Please have a look at [collapse in bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/#example)

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Dominic, on click on the `Read more >> `link should display the full content list in a separate page/ or similar and not in Home tab. For this, do we need to follow `Parent` / `Child ` component way, I mean to pass data between them ? Click on the link in the parent component and then display the child component and display full content there at child level ?

Answer (score 1):

### STEPS

1. Just add the link on the anchor tags.
2. Make sure your link contains some kind of `id` or an identifier of the content because you need to fetch the content using that identifier. Let take `id` here.

```
<section className="col2">
   <a href={slug}>
     Read more {">"}
    {">"}
  </a>
</section>
```

In you ContentDisplaySection,

1. Take the id from the url using `react-router`.
2. Use that id to fetch the content data.
3. After fetching the content data, show it to the user.

```
function ContentDisplay() {
   const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
   const { id } = useParams(); // from react-router

  React.useEffect(() => {
      fetchContentData(id)
        .then(data => setData(data));
  });

  return <div>{content}</div>
}
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {" "}
      <Navigation />{" "}
      <Switch>
        {" "}
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/tutorials" component={Tutorials} />
        <Route path="/tutorialslist" component={TutorialsList} />
        <Route path="/content/:id" component={ContentDisplaySection} />
      </Switch>{" "}
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

NOTE :- you cannot pass content from your parent to child upon link change because upon refreshing the child page, the data is lost. The data passed from parent to child component doesn't persist between page refresh.

Comment: May I know where do I need to write this function ``ContentDisplay()``. At the moment I have ``Home.js`` component where I am getting the data from contentful site. So should i write the `ContentDisplay()` in home page itself ?

Comment: Seems like you're pretty new to React. Are you using `react-router`?

Comment: Yes I have only basic knowledge in React. I am using `react-router-dom` in App.js as ``function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation/>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/tutorials" component={Tutorials} />
              <Route path="/tutorialslist" component={TutorialsList} />
          </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};`

Comment: An I have ``Navigation.js`` component too.

Comment: Use a component, put it inside the App as a route. That should do.

Comment: I have created a component `ContentDisplaySection` and added the component in App.js, like ``function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ContentDisplaySection/>
        <Navigation/>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/tutorials" component={Tutorials} />
              <Route path="/tutorialslist" component={TutorialsList} />
          </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};``

Comment: It throws error following error>>    'fetchContentData' is not defined  and 
 'content' is not defined           no-undef

Comment: I've updated the App.js. It looks to me, you have no basic concepts of how `react-router` works or even javascript in general. Do watch some tutorials on youtube and read some docs. Try to understand before doing something. Otherwise, you'll spend most of your hours looking for answers here which is not fruitful for you.

Comment: Also, `fetchContentData` is an api call which calls your API to fetch the content. You have to write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate your comments. I will follow as suggested. I usually read something and would like to build and see the outcome.